# Is there a function like Lighthouse on Google Chrome but for Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-devtools

I was wondering if there is a web tool within Mozilla Firefox that could analyse the performance, accessibility and SEO for a website/web app as Lighthouse does with Chrome : [Chrome DevTools : Lightouse report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN7Sk.png)

Thank you in advance and happy holidays !

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a pane integrated into the developer tools like Google Chrome provides, but the Google Lighthouse team does provide an extension you can use to generate a report for the page you are currently viewing: [Google Lighthouse from Firefox Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-lighthouse/)

Note that it does not work with pages running on localhost, and instead instructs you to "Use the Lighthouse [Node CLI](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse#using-the-node-cli) to audit
pages on localhost."